How to get Doctrine to accept JSON field be stored in a LONGTEXT column again?
TLDR: In Doctrine, Local development setup suddenly decided that LONGTEXT column is no valid container for JSON entity field. However, this JSON field is happily stored in a LONGTEXT column on the deployed version. How to make local environment happily conform like the deployed version?
While working on a team project I routinely check that database and schema are in sync with doctrine:schema:validate. Out of the blue, after I made some changes not involving database or entities, the schema was not valid anymore. I asked it to generate migrations in order to see where the problem was; the changes needed were about this:
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE my_entities CHANGE column column JSON NOT NULL');
}

This change belongs to the entity described as follows:
class MyEntity implements [ ... ], JsonSerializable
{
   [ ... ]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private $column = [];

As you can see, It's a JSON type of field, which in a sense proves that the fuzz about schema sync is justified, but it puzzles me that in the deployed version there is no such warning. Also, in my development environment there was no warning either until last week.
I'd generally tilt towards fixing the sync on the back-end, but due contextual reasons I'd prefer to get my local environment to not recognize the difference in the same way as the deployed version.
Ah, sql version is 8; on Ubuntu 22

If I clone the same repo in parallel, the problem disappears; which is pretty weird provided that the problem persists across branches and database resets. I will come back if I find an answer
